# Commutative property of the commands

Tags: bash, shell, taskaffinity

I need to ask this question just to double check the answer.

Does the order of the commands matter? For example:

Is this command

```
 taskset 0x2 time echo "foo"
```

equal than

```
time taskset 0x2 echo "foo"
```

?

I need to know if all the commands followed by the taskset will have the same CPU affinity or just the command immediately after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know if all the commands followed by the `taskset` will have
>   the same CPU affinity or just the command immediately after it.

Here is a little experiment:

*Start two BG tasks*

```
$ > taskset 0x2 sleep 50 & sleep 60 &
```

*Get their PIDs*

```
$ > ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18562 pts/81   00:00:00 bash
20750 pts/81   00:00:00 sleep
20751 pts/81   00:00:00 sleep
20752 pts/81   00:00:00 ps
```

*Get the CPU affinity of the known PIDs:*

```
$ > taskset -p 20750
pid 20750's current affinity mask: 2
$ > taskset -p 20751
pid 20751's current affinity mask: 3f
```

So, it seems like the CPU affinity is set for the first process only.

---

*Update (trying to explain the following behavior):*

1. `/usr/bin/time taskset 0x2 sleep 100000`=> only `sleep` gets the affinity mask `2` *(somewhat expected!)*
2. `taskset 0x2 /usr/bin/time sleep 100000` => both `time` and `sleep` get the affinity mask `2` *(need to clarify!)*

In the second case, let's call `ps -f` to get the PPID (parent PID) for each process:

```
$> taskset 0x2 /usr/bin/time sleep 60 &
[1] 5942
$> ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user      5942  9698  0 18:19 pts/261  00:00:00 /usr/bin/time sleep 60
user      5943  5942  0 18:19 pts/261  00:00:00 sleep 60
user      5944  9698  0 18:19 pts/261  00:00:00 ps -f
user      9509  9508  0 16:19 pts/261  00:00:00 -bash
user      9698  9509  0 16:20 pts/261  00:00:00 bash
$> taskset -p 5942
pid 5942's current affinity mask: 2
$> taskset -p 5943
pid 5943's current affinity mask: 2
```

What can be seen is that `sleep`'s PPID (5942) corresponds to `/usr/bin/time`'s PID (5942). IOW `sleep` is a child process of *(has been forked from*) `/usr/bin/time`. Because any child process inherits the configuration of the parent process, `sleep` will have the same CPU affinity with `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: I did this test: **taskset 0x2 /usr/bin/time sleep 100000** and both had the affinity mask: 2. But, when I did **/usr/bin/time taskset 0x2 sleep 100000** they had different affinity masks.

Comment: @carlosvega: That's probably because `sleep` is forked as a child process by `time` and inherits its configuration.

Comment: @carlosvega: still not sure if the answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure, because of what you said about sleep forking the command. So does it matter or not?

Comment: @carlosvega: Check the updated answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two different questions here - "are they equivalent?" and "is CPU affinity inherited?".

First, the two commands you list are *not* equivalent. The first:

```
taskset 0x2 time echo "foo"
```

assuming a `PATH` and similar setup to the host I'm on at the moment, is equivalent to:

```
/bin/taskset 0x2 /usr/bin/time /bin/echo "foo"
```

Which produces a process tree like this:

```
/bin/taskset
    |
    \- /usr/bin/time
            |
            \- /bin/echo
```

The second:

```
time taskset 0x2 echo "foo"
```

which is equivalent to `/bin/taskset 0x2 /bin/echo "foo"` wrapped by the `bash` builtin `time`, produces this process tree:

```
/bin/taskset
    |
    \- /bin/echo
```

In this case, there are only two external processes - the `time` part is handled internally by `bash` instead of calling `/usr/bin/time`.

To answer your second question, CPU affinity is inherited in Linux, so your first example would bind both `/usr/bin/time` and `/bin/echo` to the specified CPU sets. In the second example, since `time` is the shell builtin, it would be influenced by any CPU affinity set on `bash` itself, not by the `taskset` in the current command line.